# Fake key presses using XHB

Tags: haskell, keyboard, x11, xcb

I'm trying to simulate key presses using XHB and XTest, using this [example code](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xcb/demo/tree/app/xte/xte.c#n75) as a reference. Unfortunately, whatever I do, the resulting program has no effect. No exceptions, no warnings.

Any ideas?

I'm using XHB 0.5.2012.11.23 with GHC 7.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import Graphics.XHB
import Graphics.XHB.Gen.Test

main = do
    Just c <- connect
    let keyCode = 38  -- A
    forever $ do
        fakeInput c $ MkFakeInput (toBit' EventMaskKeyPress) keyCode 0 (fromXid xidNone) 0 0 0
        threadDelay $ 1 * 1000
        fakeInput c $ MkFakeInput (toBit' EventMaskKeyRelease) keyCode 0 (fromXid xidNone) 0 0 0
        threadDelay $ 1 * 1000

toBit' :: (BitEnum a, Integral b) => a -> b
toBit' = fromIntegral . toBit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is a bit subtle. If you look at the [XTest protocol](http://www.x.org/docs/Xext/xtest.pdf) you'll find that the `FAKE_EVENT` doesn't expect an `EVENT_MASK` but instead expects a `FAKE_EVENT_TYPE`. `KeyPress` is `FAKE_EVENT_TYPE` `2` whereas `KeyRelease` is `3`. Things work as expected after these values are used in place of `EventMaskKeyPress` and `EventMaskKeyRelease` (moreover, you don't need the nasty `toBit` coercion, which was the smell that pointed me towards this being incorrect).